# Codeigniter Active Record where value in JSON object

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a question to ask. Firstly, I have a table, where the parent has `parent_id` is `0` and the child has `parent_id` equal parent id. `parent_id` of all children are stored as a json encoded array (one child record can have many parents).

So, how can I get all the children of the parent when I pass one parent id. I tried but it won't work and I don't have a clue.

Here's the code:

```
function get_child_product($parent_id, $limit, $start) {
        $this -> db -> from('product');
        $this -> db -> where(json_decode('parent_id'), $parent_id);
        $this -> db -> limit($limit, $start);
        $this -> db -> order_by('order', 'asc');
        $this -> db -> order_by('id', 'desc');
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
        return $query -> result();
    }
```

Problem solved:

```
function get_child_product($parent_id, $limit, $start) {
        $this -> db -> from('product');
        $this -> db -> like('parent_id', '"' . $parent_id . '"');
        $this -> db -> limit($limit, $start);
        $this -> db -> order_by('order', 'asc');
        $this -> db -> order_by('id', 'desc');
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
        return $query -> result();
    }
```

Comment: can you be a little more clear? is the JSON in the database? or are you sending an array of ids to your function to get all the children of those parents?

Comment: Yes, I stored parent_id array as JSON in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a JSON encoded array in your database with the parent relationship and you want to get only children of a certain parent. The thing is that JSON objects in a database are nothing more than strings, you cannot dynamically decode them in the query and use a where clause.

You have two options:

1.Query all your children then use PHP to filter them based on the decoded JSON

2.Use mysql `like` to match a string in json format

```
function get_child_product($parent_id, $limit, $start) {
    return $this -> db -> from('product')
                    -> like('parent_id', '"parent_id":'.$parent_id)
                    -> limit($limit, $start)
                    -> order_by('order', 'asc')
                    -> order_by('id', 'desc')
                    -> get()
                    -> result();
}
```

Note that the `like` parameter should match the syntax of your JSON so if you're ids are wrapped in `"` quotes, then add them to the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't mean

```
where('parent_id', decoded($parent_id));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try `where_in` clause of `active records`:

```
function get_child_product($parent_id, $limit, $start) {
    $this -> db -> from('product');
    $this -> db -> where_in( parent_id, decoded($parent_id) ); #changes here
    $this -> db -> limit($limit, $start);
    $this -> db -> order_by('order', 'asc');
    $this -> db -> order_by('id', 'desc');
    $query = $this -> db -> get();
    return $query -> result();
}
```

Comment: Missing quotes around `'parent_id'`.