# how to get json value on condition from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, xampp, codeigniter-3

[image: See in the image where you can check the records. player1 field records are in json format. i want to get the record accordingly the phoneNumber which field are inside player1 column. i had tried to fetch the record on condition like.]

```
public function cmplFirstRdDetails($userMobileNo) {
    $this->db->from('records');
    $this->db->like('player1', '{"PhoneNumber":"$userMobileNo"}');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

This code is not working for me.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why you shouldn't store data like this in a json string. You should have a completely separate table for the players, with all of those details, and the cell in this table should contain the unique identifier for the player.

Comment: Yeah but now i'm looking for the solution. how i can fetch the records.

Comment: You'd be much better off redoing your table structure now rather than waiting. However, the reason your search does not work is because you have the curly brackets in the search, and your `$userMobileNo` variable is not being concatenated becuase you specified it as a string literal. It should be `like('player1', "%\"PhoneNumber\":\"$userMobileNo\"%")`

Comment: i think this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086465/codeigniter-active-record-where-value-in-json-object